# Does Griphook have a better chance of getting out of Gringotts with instead of without the trio?

Tags: harry-potter

(Originally part of [that](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/261438/griphook-doesnt-betray-trio-fine-but-why-does-griphook-leave-trio-in-gringott), but it was closed for not being focused.)

I think it's more risky for Griphook to try to get out of Gringotts solo vs with the trio. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

Remember that Griphook wasn't seen in the main Gringotts hall, as he was riding on Harry's shoulders under the invisibility cloak.  Bogrod probably didn't realize Griphook was there either, as Bogrod was Imperiused.

So all that the other goblins of Gringotts know is that a vault is being broken into, and somehow Griphook is there sounding the alarm.

Griphook was on the run, but not for doing anything wrong as far as Gringotts was concerned.  It seems he was simply unwilling to work with the new Death Eater regime.

It's possible there will be awkward questions later about how he got into Gringotts.  But presumably he's hoping that sounding the alarm will ingratiate him with the other goblins so that in the confusion following the robbery, the escape, and the loss of a significant part of their security (the dragon), they won't look too hard at how Griphook came to be there.  Griphook's recovery of the *real* sword of Gryffindor for the goblins might be part of this plan as well.

Comment: Thansk Kyralessa. I take it this is not necessarily your opinion but simply what Griphook may have been thinking?

Comment: 'Griphook's recovery of the real sword of Gryffindor for the goblins might be part of this plan as well.' --> Ah I think I didn't understand this at 1st but with BMWurm's comment I think I do now: '[and having "rescued" the sword makes him look far less guilty](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/261438/griphook-doesnt-betray-trio-fine-but-why-does-griphook-leave-trio-in-gringott?noredirect=1#comment720753_261438)' --> Do you mean like that?

Comment: @BCLC Of course it's my opinion.  Only JKR could answer it definitively.

Comment: Kyralessa ah wrong/unclear question. I mean you do not necessarily think that Griphook's thinking is correct (i.e. you agree with Griphook), but neverthless you do think this is what Griphook was thinking?